# Execute the function only if the order status is changed

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am working on notification task. When an admin changed order status in admin panel, I would like to execute notification function. As of now, it is working for every 30 seconds. My main task is to execute notification function only if the order status changes.

For instance, the order status of order number **001** is **Pending**. Now, admin changes this order status to **Accepted**. Then I want to execute this function and show notification in my Android App. If the order status remained same even after 30 seconds or if admin doesn't change the status, then it should not execute.

Here is the code

```
if (response != null) {
      String order_status = response.getString("order_status");
      String status_desc = response.getString("status_description");              
      createNotification(getActivity(), isLoggedIn, order_id, order_status, status_desc); // I want to execute this function only if the order status changes
}
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: You should use FCM. whenever the Admin change the status let your backend send notification through FCM.

Comment: Is it possible perform using if statement? Through api im getting the data every 30 secs

Comment: yes its possible.  if (order_status.equalsIgnoreCase("Accepted")){  createNotification(getActivity(), isLoggedIn, order_id, order_status, status_desc); }

Comment: Good. Say there are 4 order_status. What if the order status is "Accepted" and admin changes it to "Delivered". How is it possible to work in this scenario?

Comment: I am posting an answer for this

Comment: Yes Please @SahilManchanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create constants of your order status

```
final String PENDING = "pending"
    final String ACCEPTED = "accepted"
    final String DELIVERED = "delivered"

  //  Using IF
    if (order_status.equalsIgnoreCase(PENDING)){
      //execute your function according to your status
    }else if(order_status.equalsIgnoreCase(ACCEPTED)){

    }else if (order_status.equalsIgnoreCase(DELIVERED)){

    }

   // using switch case
    switch(order_status.toLowerCase()){
      case PENDING:
      //execute your function according to your status
      break;
      case ACCEPTED:
      break
      case DELIVERED:
       break;
      default:
      System.out.print("Add more cases");
    }
```

Comment: Let me test this scenario

Comment: Your function works well but here i am not able determine the order changes. How about calling api function before if statement. I think i will get the order status depending on the order id. That order status can be stored and use that in if statement. How about this?

Comment: yes. first you need to hit the api and when you get the response then use this if/switch statements to determine when to execute your function

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you have to identify status changes. Maybe you could decorate the status with a last modification time and you can check that before sending notification.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review a case, when an administrator changes the status of an order to some value and immediately (within 30 seconds) reverses his change. What should happen in this case? Apparently, no notification is sent, as order's status did not change.

Let's consider another case. What should happen if your system is down? Will user receive notifications after the system is up? The 30 seconds (or any) timeframe is not good decision as your system could be down for unknown time.

To solve your task, I'd suggest the following approach.

1. An immutable **Events** table with **event_id Number auto incremented, order_id, status, timestamp** fields. After each change to order status a row is inserted into this table.
2. **Acknowledgments** table that has **event_id, processed_timestamp** fields, this will serve as a reference to know which events have been processed. Every 30 seconds you shall retrieve events with event_id larger than last processed event from the acknowledgements table and get the latest event from the retrieved rows and send notification.